# Intrepreting/Parsing JSON data with jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, getjson

I would like to interpret data from JSON feed using jQuery getJSON.

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/raywilliamjohnson/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=30', function(data) { 
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
            updated = item.updated;
            url = item['media$group']['media$content']['url'];
            thumb = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
            numViews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
        });
    });
});
```

How to correctly interpret JSON data and assign variables to data items (ex. url, numViews, etc...)? Thanks much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `callback` GET parameter to `?` (`callback=?`), so jQuery will be able to make the JSONP request correctly and execute your callback.

Also to get the `url`, you need to access the item at index `[0]`, just like you get the `thumb`:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/raywilliamjohnson/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=30', function(data) { 
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
            var updated = item.updated;
            var url = item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'];
            var thumb = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
            var numViews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ulepo).

Comment: An important note is the addition of `var`

Comment: @Justin: Thanks, I forgot to mention it, just for the record, if you make an assignment (you miss the `var` statement) to an undeclared identifier (one that is not reachable in the scope chain), it will become member of the global object (a global variable) something that you don't really want or need...